# Show data of a Post Object field in the an ACF Group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a custom field group named "Agenda 2" using Advanced Custom Field plugin in Wordpress. Under the group, I created a Post Object field named Panelist Chair. I can't seem to pull the data in the sub field named "Panelist Chair". But I can able to pull the data from another Post Object field I created outside the group.

```
$thegroupfield = get_field('agenda_2');
print_r($thegroupfield); //this returns all the arrays which is fine

$pchair = get_field('panelist_chair');
print_r($pchair); //this doesn't return any value

$pchair = get_sub_field('panelist_chair');
print_r($pchair); //this doesn't return any value too

$mod = get_field('moderator'); //another post object field outside the group
print_r($mod); //this returns array which is fine
```

[image]

How can I get to show the data of the post object field in the group?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following? The field panelist_chair is part of your agenda_2 field. You can t acces it with a get_field function because it is inside the array of agenda_2.

$thegroupfield = get_field('agenda_2');

print_r($thegroupfield['panelist_chair'])

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the data that comes out of get_field('agenda_2').